# What is the default placeholder style?

Tags: css, html, placeholder

I want the input text style to look the same like HTML5 placeholder.
I simply would like to know, what is the default placeholder style in css.

Comment: Each browser is free to create its own default styles.

Comment: If you want default styles, then don't style the elements..?

Answer (score 0):

Each browser is free to create its own default styles

To make your own style in placeholder use `::-webkit-input-placeholder` with all standards. you can also change it onfocus like `input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder`

```css
::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    #909;
}
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color:    red;
}
:-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 4 to 18 */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
::-moz-placeholder { /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
   color:    #909;
   opacity:  1;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
   color:    #909;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Stack Snippets are awesome!">
```